# Building reusable modules in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to build a reusable JavaScript modules using Typescript. As part of my repo, I want to build out some samples (this is also part of my test framework). In my samples (also written in TypeScript), I can reference my reusable components if I point directly back to my source .ts files but I can't if I reference the compiled JS libraries. Here is my (pseudo) project structure...

```
lib/Module.js
lib/Module.d.ts
src/ts/core/Module.ts
samples/sample1/src/app.ts
samples/sample1/lib/bundle.js
samples/sample1/index.html
```

When it fails, I include my reusable modules like so:

```
import { Module1 } from '../../../lib/Module'
...
let myModule:Module1 = new Module1();
```

The error I get here is "cannot find name 'Module1'"

I can make it work with the following:

```
import { Module1 } from '../../../src/ts/core/Module'
```

I have played with the triple-slash reference tags. I've tried includes and files arguments in tsconfig.json but I can't seem to get it right. I really want my samples to mimic the way they would be used outside of this repo, where referencing the source ts files is probably not feasible.

Can anyone help me sift through this?

Worth noting that I am using Webpack to build the bundle.

Comment: you should just create separate node modules for your modules and integrate them as you would any other third party library

Comment: I guess that's the heart of my question... what is the best way to create and test distributable node modules? Any documentation pointers? I'm going through some PluralSight courses right now but would love a succinct tutorial if you know of one.